# Simple Sublime Text 3 python27 build system - add project folder to path

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to set up a very simply python 2 build system in sublime text 3.

The default build environment for python works, but I want to be able to import top level modules of the project by adding the project folder to `PYTHONPATH`.

Here is my attempt at a build system:

```
{
  "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
  "env": 
  {
      "PYTHONPATH": "$project_path"
  },
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

The terminal pops up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\project", line 4, in <module>
    from lib.util.utilities import pairwise
ImportError: No module named lib.util.utilities
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

It's not seeing the `$project_path` folder, otherwise it would be able to import utilities, as `lib/` is a folder in the top level project folder. How can I fix this?

I am on x64 Windows 8.1

Comment: Is lib a module? I.e. does it contain a `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @ThinkChaos Yes, lib contains a `__init__.py`.

Comment: Are you sure your build system is the one being used?

Comment: Yes, it is the one that is selected under `Tools->Build System->my_python2_build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my tests, and to [a post on Sublime Text's forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14511), variables are not expanded in `env`.

I found this by running the following Python code with your build system:

```
import os

print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
```

Which outputs: `$project_path`.

Using the following build system will work, though you have the overhead of spawning a shell whenever you run your code:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "export PYTHONPATH=\"$project_path\"; python -u \"$file\"",
    "windows":
    {
        "shell_cmd": "set \"PYTHONPATH=$project_path\" & python -u \"$file\"",
    },
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

This works for me on both OS X and Windows with the following setup:

```
te st
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── util.py
├── src
│   └── te st.py
└── test.sublime-project
```

Comment: I get that `'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]` is this a default windows shell command?

Comment: Right, Windows forgot about that; sorry!

Comment: @user27886 I fixed it to work with spaces on Windows too.

Comment: That's what happens with `set "PYTHONPATH=$project_path"`. I added a working project structure for you to compare with yours.